# .NET API with Google OAuth and React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, google-oauth

I'm quite new to ASP .NET and I want to set up an API which uses authentication using Google OAuth and stores the user details of new users in a database. I also want to use React to connect to the api and consume it.
If there is a straightforward resource, I'd appreciate it if you could redirect me to there.

I've followed so many tutorials, getting more and more confused with topics like BFFs, DuendeServer, etc.
First, I tried using the template provided by Visual Studio for React SPA with Identity and tried adding AddGoogle to the Configuration, but this couldn't process the request redirected from Google and the details of the request were visible in the address bar (like the scope, state, etc.
Then, I got through documentation and tried setting up DuendeServer as well, and I couldn't understand any of it.
I tried testing both of these options through just the browser. The main issue that I have encountered is that the final redirect to /signin-google is not being processed by the .NET server.
I haven't been able to move past the authentication stage and haven't even been able to think about how I would go about saving the user details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -3):

Setting up OAuth authentication with Google in an ASP.NET Core API and connecting it to a React frontend can be a bit complex, but I can provide you with a general guide to help you get started. I'll also suggest some resources that might be helpful:

1. **Set Up Google OAuth Authentication:**

   - Make sure you have a Google Developer Console project set up.
   - Create OAuth 2.0 credentials for your project and specify the authorized redirect URIs.
   - In your ASP.NET Core API, you can use the `AddAuthentication` and `AddGoogle` methods in your `Startup.cs` to configure Google authentication. Ensure that you've installed the necessary NuGet packages for authentication and identity.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID";
        options.ClientSecret = "YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET";
    });
```

2. **React Frontend Integration:**

   - In your React app, you can use a library like `react-oauth/google` to handle the OAuth flow.
3. **Saving User Details:**

   - Once the user is authenticated with Google, you can access their details in the authentication middleware in your ASP.NET Core API. You can access the user's information like email, name, etc., from the `HttpContext.User` object.

```cs
var user = HttpContext.User;
var email = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
var name = user.Identity.Name;
```

4. **Database Integration:**

   - To save user details, you can use Entity Framework Core or any other preferred database technology. You'll need to create a user table and store the relevant user information there.
5. **Testing and Debugging:**

   - To debug the authentication process, use logging to capture the relevant details and any errors that might occur.
   - Ensure that the redirect URIs in your Google Developer Console project match what you've configured in your ASP.NET Core app.

Remember that integrating authentication can be complex, so take it step by step, and don't hesitate to consult the documentation and seek help on developer forums or communities if you encounter specific issues.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Right now, I should be fine with authentication only so I am thinking of doing that on the react frontend with react-oauth package and then sending the credentials to the backend for storing in database.
I will try out your suggestions in the future.